# Mesh with star topology

Tags: arduino-uno, nrf24l01+

In my project I have an issue. I have more than 2 mesh network with Arduino + nRF240L01 with a star topology (one Arduino is master another 6 Arduino + nRF240L01 are the slaves likewise I can be able to have more than 2 networks).

So I want to communicate only with one mesh network but not to another. Is the different addressing enough to separate the networks? And I would like to have sample code as well.

Comment: Ideally you'd pick a different channel too - that way they won't interfere with each other on a physical level.

Comment: found this .... http://tmrh20.github.io/RF24Network/ .....  maybe you can use tree topology